# Variable as table name in pgsql AND using prepared statements

Tags: postgresql, triggers, statements

Is there any way to get this working. My remit from the DBA is to use prepared statements so I'm having to migrate off of my current as I am told it's causing performance issues

```
    EXECUTE format('INSERT INTO %I SELECT %L, %L, $1.*', TG_TABLE_NAME || '_audit', TG_OP, now(), NEW.*)
```

I have tried this

```
    declare
            target_table varchar(50) := TG_TABLE_NAME || '_audit';
        begin
        case
            when TG_OP = 'INSERT' then
                PREPARE stmt as INSERT INTO target_table VALUES (TG_OP, now(), NEW.*);
                EXECUTE stmt;
                DEALLOCATE stmt;
                RETURN NEW;
```

which results in 'relation target_table does not exist'
and this, which does not compile

```
                PREPARE stmt as INSERT INTO $1 VALUES (TG_OP, now(), NEW.*);
                EXECUTE stmt WITH target_table;
```

and this which does not compile:

```
                PREPARE stmt as INSERT INTO TG_TABLE_NAME || '_audit' VALUES (TG_OP, now(), NEW.*);
                EXECUTE stmt;
```

and a few other variations..

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the function `format()`. Using a prepared statement inside a trigger function, is kind of odd. I also don't see why the old code is slow and the new one would be fast. It's just a straight forward INSERT. If your DBA knows better, he could show it to you